In JWT Authentication in .NET 7, how can a "validated" token be "missing"?
I am in a strange situation with my .NET 7 web app. According to my application logs, my token is not found but still validated in some way which does not make sense to me. I need to get my controller method called. I used this web page to understand JWT Authentication in .NET 7.
I have the following code in my Program.cs:
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
        builder.Services.AddAuthentication(cfg => {
            cfg.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            cfg.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            cfg.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options => {
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.SaveToken = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("UwSuperGeheimeSleutelDieLangGenoegIs12345678")
                ),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("OnAuthenticationFailed: " + context.Exception.Message);
                    if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
                    {
                        context.Response.Headers.Add("Token-Expired", "true");
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnMessageReceived = context =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("OnMessageReceived: " + context.Token);
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Token))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Token is missing from the request.");
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnTokenValidated = context =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("OnTokenValidated: " + context.SecurityToken);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnChallenge = context =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("OnChallenge: " + context.Error + " - " + context.ErrorDescription);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });
        var token = TokenGenerator.GenerateJWTToken("Daan", Guid.NewGuid());
        Console.WriteLine("TOKEN START");
        Console.WriteLine(token);
        Console.WriteLine("TOKEN END");
        var app = builder.Build();
        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.MapControllers();
        app.Run();
    }
}

I have the following controller method:
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("checkclaims")]
        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult CheckClaims()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Not yet implemented");
        }
    }

And this is my token generation:
    public static class TokenGenerator
    {
        public static string GenerateJWTToken(string userName, Guid id)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim> {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, id.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName),
            };
            var jwtToken = new JwtSecurityToken(
                claims: claims,
                notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
                expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30),
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(
                    new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("UwSuperGeheimeSleutelDieLangGenoegIs12345678")
                    ),
                    SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            );
            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwtToken);
        }
    }

I try to call my web api like this in VSCode REST Client
GET https://localhost:7126/api/Values/checkclaims
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxLzA0L3htbGRzaWctbW9yZSNobWFjLXNoYTI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1laWRlbnRpZmllciI6ImVhZGRjYTdmLTBkYTMtNGU1Yy1iYzdkLThhM2Y3OWJmODg1ZCIsImh0dHA6Ly9zY2hlbWFzLnhtbHNvYXAub3JnL3dzLzIwMDUvMDUvaWRlbnRpdHkvY2xhaW1zL25hbWUiOiJEYWFuIiwibmJmIjoxNzE3Njg1Nzk4LCJleHAiOjE3MjAyNzc3OTh9.Jwp70J6IfHHvkrG0uu0dXrBxHcRBNthhKzkTMW6wNjo

And this is my response of my application:
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Date: Thu, 06 Jun 2024 14:57:20 GMT
Server: Kestrel
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer

With this output:
OnMessageReceived:
Token is missing from the request.
OnTokenValidated: {"alg":"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha256","typ":"JWT"}.{"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier":"eaddca7f-0da3-4e5c-bc7d-8a3f79bf885d","http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name":"Daan","nbf":1717685798,"exp":1720277798}

Normally, logging helps me to solve an issue but this is just confusing.
Why isn't my controller method called?
Why is my token "validated" but also "missing"?
And last but not least, how can I make sure my controller method is called?

Can you provide more information about context in the discussed scenario? Are you sure you had a bearer token?

Good point. The token used in generated by the app and logged to the console. Considering the code, this should be the bearer code. Right? What else can it be? Please note that the code is the way it is. There is not more relevant code in my app.

It seems that this happens when the authentication succeeded at the IDP and it is about to send out a bearer token to the SP, but a field called Token (not to be confounded with the Bearer Token that is being added IF we have a token, among other criteria) is null or empty. I believe the Token is a registration token. I will write an answer on short notice.

Daan, scratch that, after rereading your question, it's clear that the token is the JWT token, so I was wrong in my previous comment and it so happens that the authentication happened successfully, but the token to be passed as the bearer token is missing for some reason.

I think you need to change the order of UseAuthorization() and UseAuthentication() in your startup.
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

The UseAuthentication middleware is responsible for setting the User property of the HttpContext, which is then used by the UseAuthorization middleware to authorize the user. If UseAuthentication is called after UseAuthorization, the User property will not be set when the authorization middleware runs, resulting in an unauthorized error.

First, let's understand how JWT works in general. These are the steps:

the SP (Service Provider, or client app) wants to authenticate
so it is either redirecting to the IDP (Identity Provider) or it's sending some request to it (like a cURL request, for example)
the IDP resolves the identity of the requestor (if the identity already has an IDP session, then good, otherwise authentication on the IDP level will be necessary)
then, the IDP encodes some valuable data into JWT (JSON Web Token) and sends it back to the SP, either as a Bearer Token (like in your case) or a POST parameter, so there are multiple options for that
the SP receives the JWT decrypts it and proceeds with its work

Now, your issue happens on the IDP's side as it seems, because we are inside AddJwtBearer, so we want to add JWT as a Bearer Token, that is, we provide an identity, therefore we are at the IDP. As we can see, token is empty in this case, so it was either not created in this scenario, or it was not properly initialized, or it was removed, etc., but the validation that succeeded referred to the authentication before getting to the token generation.
So, from the information I have seen it very much seems that the authentication was successful at the IDP's side, that is, your username/password was correct, but the token was not created (yet) or was not properly passed.

My last question is "How can I make sure my controller method is called?" What code change exactly do I need to make to make this work?

@Daan unfortunately my .NET period passed before JWT became fashionable and currently I'm programming JWT for PHP, so I'm not sure how you could achieve that. But based on the code, seeing that you have a OnMessageReceived, I would search for OnMessageReceived or MessageReceived in the code and see how the event is triggered and how the context is created or passed. Probably you would need to call it at that point and assign it to the context. But I'm speculating, as I did not work on JWT in .NET.
